Мой код выводит ссылку на функцию, а мне нужно её значение
print(lambda x = int(input()): x * x + x)
Я хотел использовать ввод несколько раз в одной строке и понял, что могу использовать лямбда функцию, но она работает не так, как я предполагал. Помогите решить проблему в пределах одной строки и подскажите более простые варианты решения подобной задачи в одну строку, если знаете.

Напишите входные и выходные данные. "использовать ввод несколько раз в одной строке" - я это читаю как ввод чисел через пробел, верно?

Какую задачу вы решаете?

@StanislavVolodarskiy, просто любопытство, но часто бывают ситуации, когда так и хочется сократить код на 1-2 строчки, например, вычисление какой-нибудь функции от некого X. Приходится объявлять переменную для ввода и затем выводить результат: целых 2 строчки. А теперь я знаю, как это делать в 1 строчку)

Тогда вам будет интересно узнать что любую программу с вводом и выводом можно записать в одну строку. Вообще любую.

@StanislavVolodarskiy, где это можно узнать, если не секрет?

SICP, и Y combinator. Первый про то что рекурсия заменяет циклы, второй про анонимные рекурсивные функции.

Вы может ввести любые данные, обработать их рекурсивно, не определяя ни одного символа. Держите вычисление факториала: print((lambda f, n: f(f, n))((lambda f, n: 1 if n == 0 else n * f(f, n - 1)), int(input()))).

Если к этому добавить замену линейной рекурсии на древовидную, то ограниченный размер стека в Питоне не помешает: однострочная программа будет работать не хуже многострочной.

Только один вопрос: зачем? Люди бьются над упрощением проблем, разбивая их на составные части. А однострочники - шаг в противоположном наравлении. Как вы будете отлаживать нагромождение вложенных лямбд в строке длиной 60 тысяч символов?

@StanislavVolodarskiy, зачем? Чистое любопытство. Многое может пригодиться в нашем нелегком деле. Я не однострочник, просто люблю сокращать код, но не до такой степени, чтобы уместить "60 тысяч символов" в 1 строку)

@StanislavVolodarskiy, крутой факториал.

Лямбда описывает функцию. После этого её ещё нужно вызвать, то есть написать скобки после неё. И чтобы было понятно, к чему относятся эти скобки, придётся и всю лямбду тоже в скобки взять:
print((lambda x = int(input()): x * x + x)())

P.S. Если очень хочется, то можно и через ; написать несколько строк кода в одной строке. Но так делать очень не рекомендуется по причинам не очень хорошей читаемости такого кода:
x = int(input()); print(x * x + x)

Впрочем, код с лямбдой тоже не так, чтобы очень читаемый. Я бы описание лямбды и её вызов делал на отдельных строках.

Спасибо, именно то, что мне нужно.

Но почему не print((lambda x: x * x + x)(int(input())))? Зачем нужно значение по умолчанию, когда есть  просто значение?

@StanislavVolodarskiy Да, лучше так, наверное )  Просто я код автора вопроса не сильно менял

@StanislavVolodarskiy, ещё более гибкий код, идеально.

Не уверен, что под одной строкой ты имел именно это, но предложу такой вариант:
f = lambda x: x * x + x; print(f(int(input())))

Точка с запятой позволяет записывать выражения в одну строку, как ты и просишь.
Про lambda здесь написано достаточно подробно.

Если использовать ; и объединять несколько строк в одну, то лямбда и не нужна, можно обычное выражение написать и посчитать. )

Спасибо, впервые вижу такую фичу, как точка с запятой, как я без этого жил?

@oguzok Но вообще лучше не использовать ; без крайней нужды. Это запутывает читающего код.

@oguzok вообще не нужно все в одну строку пытаться объединять

@insolor, я не объединяю ВСЁ в 1 строчку, я сокращаю код, чтобы удовлетворить мой перфекционизм, а если код в пару строк, например, для какого-нибудь простенького задания, не грех и объединить их.

@oguzok вот у вас неправильный перфекционизм, не нужно так "сокращать" код. Нужно чтобы он был читаемый. Вот так слеплять инпут, лямбду и принт в одну строку не нужно. Если для вас "иеальное" - это какое-то "месиво" кода - ну ок (пока вы это никуда не выносите). Но в целом так делать не нужно. Вот именно, что "грех", даже для короткого кода.

@insolor, я ещё только школьник, я не для кого-то делаю, а в основном для тестов на всяких сайтах. А там важны время выполнения и длина кода. Вот для программистов - это полезный совет, согласен.

@oguzok то что вы в одну строку все "смяли" на время выполнения никак не повлияет. Задания на длину кода - это только узкий класс заданий типа "код-гольф".

Представленные варианты ответов работают только если вводить одно число. Что если нужно обработать одновременный ввод нескольких чисел? @Amgarak задал справедливый вопрос.
Вариант вычислений для ввода нескольких чисел через пробел (одно число тоже отрабатывает) на основе генератора. На выходе - список вычисленных значений. Если заменить квадратные скобки на круглые, то получим полный генератор, который будет возвращать по одному числу.
print([x * x + x for x in (int(x) for x in input().split() if x.isdigit())])

P.S. Код отфильтровывает "мусорный" ввод. Все что не является числом, отбрасывается.
Более продвинутый вариант. Позволяет обрабатывать числа со знаком и float.
import re

print(
    [
        x * x + x
        for x in (int(x[1]) for x in re.finditer(r'([+-]?\d+)\.?\d*', input()))
    ]
)


Спасибо, очень занятный код, не знаю использую ли я его когда-нибудь, на такие комплексные проблемы пару строк я точно не пожалею)
